# Mostrar resultado en casilla mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Buenas estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora simple pero tengo problemas al mostrar el resultado final de la operacion.
Esta es la parte de mi Html del boton SUMA y el resultado quisiera mostrarlo en el input RESULTADO que esta mas abajo.

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="butSum">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="butSum">+</label>
</div>
-----------------------
<div class="col-3">
    <h3>Resultado</h3>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="resultado" disabled>
</div>
--------------------------------
```

Mi codigo javascript es el siguiente:

```
function calcularNum(){
var n1=document.getElementById('num1');
var N1=parseInt(n1.value);
var n2=document.getElementById('num2');
var N2=parseInt(n2.value);  
const signo=document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input');
    
if(signo=='+'){
    var result=N1+N2; 
    //document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=parseInt(result.value);
    document.getElementById('resultado')=result.value;
```

Parece que no puede captar el contenido del boton('+') y almacenarlo en signo. Necesito ayuda por favor.

Comment: La variable `result` debería ser numérica (o cadena, en caso de errores), quita el `.value` y con eso aparecerá en el input.

Answer (score 2):

La línea

```
document.getElementById('resultado')=result.value;
```

debería ser algo como

```
document.getElementById('resultado').value=result;
```

porque result es un número, no tiene un atributo value, mietras que `document.getElementById('resultado')` obtiene un Objeto [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), que sí tiene una propiedad value.

Pero esto sólo no te arregla el principal problema:

```
const signo = document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input');
```

El método getElement**s**ByClassName devuelve **una lista** de elementos, no un único elemento. No tengo muy claro qué intentas hacer aquí, pero no es la manera de obtener la operación que está seleccionada.

Si actualizas la pregunta podremos añadir más detalles a las respuestas